# Which dogs shed the least?

Tags: dogs, maintenance

My son want a puppy like yesterday.  We will be going to an animal donation center tomorrow.  My wife is adamant that it has be be a dog that doesn't shed fur.  I don't know if such a breed exists, but I know some shed less fur than others.

Comment: This is a easy Google search. Poodle crosses, Maltese. Some long haired dogs shed very little and some short coats shed a lot.

Comment: Are you looking for a large breed or small. How much exercise are you reasonably going to be able to provide. On a side note have you considered the cost of vaccination, registration, cost of feeding it etc?

Comment: We had a larger dog in the past so we are familiar with responsibilities and costs you mentioned.  We would like a smaller one this time.

Comment: @SAMA The goal of pets.se is to have the answers to all pet related that are a good fit for our model.  Google has lots of answers, and the best answer google finds should be here.

Comment: The list on http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/characteristics/low-shed-dogs is good, it has the name and a picture of each breed. It will take someone more skilled than me to put it as an answer. Here is some of the smaller breeds Tibetan Terrier. 
Maltese Terrier. 
Shih Tzu. 
Brussels Griffon. 
Portugese Water Dog. 
Soft-Coated Wheaten Terrier. 
Poodle (Toy, Miniature, and Standard) 
West Highland White Terrier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is part of [Pet's Spring Cleaning Campaign](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/spring-cleaning-campaign-on-pets-se). This question is old, but this answer will still help people with the same problem.

---

### Hypoallergenic dogs:

You're looking for a hypoallergenic dog.

A hypoallergenic dog means this:

> A hypoallergenic dog breed is a dog breed that is purportedly more compatible with allergic people than are other breeds.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoallergenic_dog_breed))

In reality, there isn't such thing as a *true* hypoallergenic dog, but a dog that is far less allergenic than others.

[mayoclinic.org](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/pet-allergy/symptoms-causes/syc-20352192#:%7E:text=There%27s%20no%20such%20thing%20as,urine%20of%20dogs%20and%20cats.) agrees:

> There's no such thing as a hypoallergenic dog breed, although some individual dogs may cause fewer allergy symptoms than others. Many people think that pet allergies are caused by a dog's or cat's fur, but the real source of pet allergies is often a protein that's in the saliva and urine of dogs and cats.

### Things to look for

You want to look for short coats and hair rather than fur.

I would also recommend reaching out to the shelter or breeder to ask if you could spend a few hours with the dog, to see if your allergies react.

The above two options are backed up by [helix.northwestern.edu](https://web.archive.org/web/20210816105637/http://helix.northwestern.edu/article/fido-fact-or-fiction-truth-about-hypoallergenic-pets#:%7E:text=However,%20several%20veterinarians%20and%20allergy,truly%20hypoallergenic%20pup%20or%20kitty.&text=%E2%80%9CThese%20dogs%20have%20hair%20instead,to%20see%20how%20they%20react.%E2%80%9D):

> “These dogs have hair instead of fur. Their hair grows much as a human’s does,” Becker said. “We usually advise people with allergies to spend a few hours with our dogs just to see how they react.”

Other than that, the only thing you can do is to Google the breed (if you know what it is).

### Examples of hypoallergenic dogs:

Most to all poodle crosses are somewhat hypoallergenic (including the Goldendoodle, Labradoodle, Aussiedoodle, and my personal favorite - the Bernedoodle).

The following is a short list taken from [here](https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/hypoallergenic-dogs/page/3/) and [here](https://www.pumpkin.care/blog/best-hypoallergenic-dogs/) (which have more detail and pictures). More near hypoallergenic dogs can be found [here](https://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/characteristics/low-shed-dogs) and [here](https://www.petfinder.com/dog-breeds/collections/hypoallergenic-dogs/). There are many more wonderful hypoallergenic dogs out there, so don't limit your research to this list:

(links are to Wikipedia)

- [Affenpinscher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affenpinscher)
- [Afghan Hound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghan_Hound?wprov=srpw1_0)
- [American Hairless Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Hairless_Terrier)
- [Barbado da Terceira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbado_da_Terceira)
- [Barbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbet_%28dog%29?wprov=srpw1_2)
- [Bedlington Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Water_Dog)
- [Bichon Frise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bichon_Frise?wprov=srpw1_0)
- [Bolognese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolognese_%28dog%29?wprov=srpw1_3)
- [Chinese Crested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Crested_Dog?wprov=srpw1_0)
- [Coton de Tulear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coton_de_Tulear)
- [Giant Schnauzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Schnauzer)
- [Irish Water Spaniel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Water_Spaniel)
- [Kerry Blue Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerry_Blue_Terrier)
- [Lagotto Romagnolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagotto_Romagnolo)
- [Löwchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wchen)
- [Maltese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_dog)
- [Miniature Schnauzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_Schnauzer)
- [Peruvian Inca Orchid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peruvian_Inca_Orchid)
- [Poodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poodle) (Miniature, Toy, and Standard)
- [Portuguese Water Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Water_Dog)
- [Soft Coated Wheaten Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft-coated_Wheaten_Terrier)
- [Spanish Water Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Water_Dog)
- [Standard Schnauzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Schnauzer)
- [Wire Fox Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_Fox_Terrier)
- [Xoloitzcuintli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Water_Dog)
- [Yorkshire Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorkshire_Terrier)